# unexpected real constant underflow (Fortran and R)

Tags: r, fortran, precision

I am trying to convert someone else's fortran program into a subroutine so that I can call it from R. I am compiling the fortran program (called 'midpSS9.f') by calling

```
R CMD SHLIB midpSS9.f
gfortran -m64      -02 -mtune=core2 -c midpSS9.f -o midpSS9.o
```

but I am getting several (essentially identical) warnings:

```
Warning: Real constant underflows its kind at (1)
midpSS9.f:59.44
    if (part3 .e. 0.0) part3 = 1.0E-307
                                       1
```

I am declaring the part3 variable to be a real at the top of the subroutine. From my understanding (taken from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/fortran/fortran_numbers.htm)), the smallest number should be 0.5E–308 if you are working on a 64-but machine (which I am). So, why would this be complaining here?

PS: This is my first time working with fortran, sorry if this is obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this expression,

```
part3 = 1.0E-307
```

the right-hand side is single-precision because the `E` notation is used; to make it double-precision, simply replace `E` by `D` (or `d`), so that

```
part3 = 1.0D-307
```

One more concern is that `part3` needs to be declared as a double-precision variable. Please note that `real :: part3` declares `part3` as single-precision, so we need to use something like `real(8) :: part3` or a more portable way like

```
use iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
real(dp) :: part3
```

(this may need a rather new version of compiler). With this kind of precision parameter, one can also write a double-precision literal as

```
part3 = 1.0e-307_dp
```

A good point of this approach is that one can change the precision of all literals by simply changing the definition of `dp` and switching between single- and double-precision as desired. If this is the case, names like `rk` (= "real kind") rather than `dp` (= "double precision") might be better to avoid ambiguity.